# Redirecting Subprocess.Popen stdout to a file on a remote server

Tags: python, popen, remote-server

I am trying to use subprocess.Popen to run shell commands through Python on a Ubuntu VM. However I need the output of this command to go to a file that resides on another VM.

I already have that file open using the paramiko.SSHClient module and through client.open_sftp.

But when I pass that for the stdout in Popen, Python complains saying

"AttributeError: 'SFTPFile' object has no attribute 'fileno'

How can I have Popen send its stdout to a file on a remote VM?

My code looks something like this

```
MyClient = paramiko.SSHClient()
MyClient.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
MyClient.load_system_host_keys()
MyClient.connect(args.serverip, username="xxx", password='yyy')
MySftp = MyClient.open_sftp()

RemoteLogFile = MySftp.file('/home/xxx/regression.log', "a")

...

p1 = subprocess.Popen([ShellCommand], cwd='/tmp/', shell=True, stdout=RemoteLogFile)
```

Comment: You can't, directly. You will need to read the output from the process yourself and then send it to your desired destination. Possibly just using the `communicate` method (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) will be sufficient to get the output.